# Why is Rails trying to autoload this file in a production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, require, autoload, eager-loading

This is Rails v5.2.3. I have a particular Sidekiq job where many instances of the job seem to hang for 20+ minutes. In the same machine the queue resides on, while this is happening, I can run the same code in a Rails console and it finishes in 5 seconds.

I determined the offending PID from the Sidekiq screen, and ran:

`kill -TTIN <pid>`

The following lines appeared twice in the file, which I guess means that two threads from the same process were trying to load the same file:

```
Oct 13 17:04:08 myapp-production sidekiq[1217886]: /myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:35:in `parent'
Oct 13 17:04:08 myapp-production sidekiq[1217886]: /myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:516:in `load_missing_constant'
Oct 13 17:04:08 myapp-production sidekiq[1217886]: /myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
Oct 13 17:04:08 myapp-production sidekiq[1217886]: /myapp/releases/20221013144458/lib/mixins/query_builder.rb:294:in `generate_sql'
```

I do have some `require`s in my code in different places, which I just determined is bad apparently. However, I'm not `require`ing the file listed above: `lib/mixins/query_builder.rb`. It is a module that is `extend`ed from a few different classes in `lib/classes`.

In my `config/application.rb` file, I have:

```
    config.enable_dependency_loading = true
    config.eager_load_paths += %W[
      #{config.root}/app/actions
      #{config.root}/app/organizers
      #{config.root}/lib/my_stuff
      #{config.root}/lib/mixins
      #{config.root}/lib/classes
    ]

    config.autoload_paths += %W[
      #{config.root}/app/actions
      #{config.root}/app/organizers
      #{config.root}/lib
      #{config.root}/lib/my_stuff
      #{config.root}/lib/mixins
      #{config.root}/lib/classes
      #{config.root}/lib/*
```

I admit that this is a mess, and I'm not sure what is going on here. I do have `config.eager_load` set to true in production and false in development.

So, if `lib/mixins` is present in both `eager_load_paths` and `autoload_paths`, why is the ActiveSupport's `const_missing` being triggered? And what should I do to remedy this situation?

Also, would I be better served by making this `QueryBuilder` an object that I can create an instance of to avoid two threads using the same program. In other words, is `extend` the wrong approach to lending the features within `QueryBuilder` to multiple classes?

As a second request, if anyone can point me in the right direction on the correct way to configure my `eager_load_paths` and `autoload_paths`, that will help a great deal prior to upgrading this app.

Thanks very kindly in advance for your help.

Comment: Your code doesn't do any of it's own creation of threads manually, right? The only threads involved are threads Sidekiq is managing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answer for "why I am seeing autoloads".

Autoloading may still happen during eager loading.

Let's imagine you have

```rb
class Foo
  include QueryBuilder
end
```

If Rails is eager loading `Foo` and at that point `lib/mixins/query_builder.rb` was not been visited yet, the mere evaluation of `foo.rb` triggers the autoload of `QueryBuilder` in line 2.

That configuration is a bit of a mess (as you said). We could work on simplifying it you liked.

Why is the job taking +20 minutes and 5 in the console? Don't know if it is related to this. When Sidekiq launches, the application has booted and files have been eager loaded already.

Comment: Yes, would very much like to work on simplifying it. Deeply appreciate your answer and would like to explore further.